# Chinese instead of Japanese character in firefox

Tags: 20.04, fonts, browser, language-support

I am learning Japanese with the website Wanikani and I am using their [Community](https://community.wanikani.com) . There I have noticed that the character 直　is displayed in

its Chinese version [image]instead of
the Japanese version [image].

In Chrome the Japanese version is displayed correctly, as well as in a terminal or text editors.

My font settings in Firefox are:
[image]

In answer to the comment by @Ray below:
On http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml I find the Chinese version as 76f4.

This is also the Code given by the Japanese dictionary https://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%B4%20%23kanji . This page says:

```
1-36-30     JIS X 0208-1997 kuten code
76f4    Unicode hex code
```

In Firefox this latter page has displayed its URL in the address bar as the Chinese version of the character. Is the encoding %E7%9B%B4%20%23 related to Unicode?

Comment: Would you know if the Unicode (or whatever encoding you're using) for these two character differs?  I guess what I'm thinking is if the page you're looking at is using the Chinese Unicode value instead of the Japanese Unicode value.  If so, then I guess it is "their" fault and not your's.  I've always thought they'd be different, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: I am not sure. On the page https://jisho.org/search/%E7%AB%A5 the character is displayed in the address bar in its Chinese version. Is %E7%AB%A5 related to the Unicode?

Comment: @Ray See also the edit of my question.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I can't decide if having the same Unicode is a good or bad thing!  For example, I just used Google translate (J to C) to get the Chinese character for 直.  When I copied and pasted that in, the Japanese character appears...  Does that mean you can't have a web page / document with a mix of Japanese and Chinese (if both are using Unicode)?  I type in Japanese and never thought of this...something to think more later.  But, thank you for the insight!

Comment: I think you can have a J/C mixed page if you specify the language at each change (there should be a html tag for this). I don't know how many characters have common Unicode but have different writings.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Japanese as Preferred Language in the Firefox settings
resolved the problem.

Thanks to a tip in https://community.wanikani.com/t/two-different-versions-of-%E7%9B%B4/46339

[image]